# Create new Object with filter from another Object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of Objects from backend like this:

```js
items = [{
    id: 0
    name: "example1"
    price: 15
    sizes: [10, 12, 15.5]
    types: ["one", "two"]
  },
  {
    id: 1
    name: "example2"
    price: 15
    sizes: [10, 12, 15.5]
    types: ["one", "two"]
  }
]
```

I'm receiving id as props and use find() like this:

```js
let addedItem = items.find((item) => item.id === id)
```

And as result (for id = 0):

```js
addedItem = {
  id: 0
  name: "example1"
  price: 15
  sizes: [10, 12, 15.5]
  types: ["one", "two"]
}
```

I'm getting also data like this type(1), size(0) as props.
So how can I create new Object like this?:

```js
item = {
  id: 0
  name: "example1"
  price: 15
  size: 10
  type: "two"
}
```

Comment: You can just assign the values to a new object, or what is your problem exactly?

Comment: Do you want to just find an item by multiple parameters, or do you *actually* want to return a new object reference with the other array properties removed?

Comment: Well, it will be great to find an item by multiple parameters if it's easier. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just format the new object.

```
let item = items.find((item) => item.id === id)
let formattedItem = {
    id: item.id,
    name: item.name
    price: item.price
    size: item.sizes[0]
    type: item.types[0]
}
```

I would also check if *sizes* is a valid array, for example

```
type: item.types.length ? item[0] : null
```

Comment: So, David Lacedonia, as I understand right,  if I receive size and type dinamically, I can use  for size: item.sizes[size] and for type: item.types[type]?

Comment: exactly, yes! ... and don't forget to check if types/sizes is a valid array, otherwise it would throw an error, because you cannot access [type] of undefined (for example)

Comment: array::find can return undefined so remember to check if returned `item` is truthy before trying to also access `id`, `name`, `price`, `sizes`, and `types` properties.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use hardcoded indexes to get the values in the client-side, this should be handled in the server-side only but still, if you want to make it work this will do it.
If you want the type[1] and size[0] you can use map() to structure your result object.

```
let addedItem = items.find((item) => item.id === id).map(x => {
     return {
        id: x.id,
        name: x.name,
        price: x.price,
        size: x.size[0],
        type: x.type[1]
     })
```

Comment: Singh, I receive type and size as props (type(1), size(0)  - just examples which I received)

Comment: Got it so you can use variables instead of hard-coded values (type[1] and size[0] to type[type_index] and size[size_index])  but map() is the function that should solve your problem. If the solution worked please mark it.

Comment: Singh, how can I create new Object if I don't wanna list all params by handle?

Comment: It's not working - items.find().map is not a function. I think because of items.find() return an Object (not array)

Comment: You can use filter() instead of find()

Answer (score 0):

Well, thanks for everybody. My answer:

```js
let item = items.find((item) => item.id === id)
let formattedItem = {
    ...item,
    size: item.sizes[size]
    type: item.types[type]
}
```